# How do I send a Git patch series from within Mutt?

Tags: git, mutt

Suppose I have generated a patch series in a Git repository using `git format-patch --thread --cover-letter -2`. This produces three files: `0001-cover-letter.patch`, `0002-Add-another-thing.patch`, and `0003-Add-something.patch`.

Now, I am inside Mutt and I want to send those three files to a particular email address (e.g. a mailing list). How can I actually send those three patches from within Mutt?

Comment: How is this different from attaching any 3 files to a message in mutt?

Comment: @Juancho Some open source projects (e.g. Linux) prefer patches to be "inline" rather than in attachments.

Comment: how about: `git format-patch --thread --cover-letter -2 HEAD^ | neomutt -f - recipient@example.com`? This doesn't need you to be in neomutt session.